# OpenMP - Parallel node insertion in linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, fortran, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a CFD software (written in FORTRAN) which uses particles for the calculations. I already understand the concept of tasks and performing parallel work on already created list nodes (see: http://openmp.org/sc13/sc13.tasking.ruud.pdf).

My question is: is it possible to parallelize the creation/insertion on new nodes on a linked list?

I've been trying to do so, without success so far.

Does any one know some source of information that implements a parallel linked list insertion/creation function?

Comment: Linked list are very alien to parallelism. Use arrays instead wherever possible! At least in flow solvers and particle tracking codes it should be possible.

Comment: What they do in the linked tutorial is that they assume that the work you do at each node of the list is time-consuming enough to warrant a separate task. It is very probably your insertion and creation will not be worth it. I polished your question and kept the last sentence, but you should not ask for tutorials here. Consider deleting your last sentence.

Comment: Thanks. It may not be indeed worthy to paralelize list insertion. I'll concentrate on more task intensive parts of the code.

Comment: You could use a lock-free list (cf. https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/775.pdf).